# Simple vertical jcarousel not working

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm trying to reproduce the vertical jcarousel example show by the author in this page:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html

here is my html code:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <link href="skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.jcarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
             vertical: true,
             scroll: 2
         });
     });

</script>

</head>

<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="FinKaynDiv">

     <div id="slider">

   <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango"> 
                <li>Image1</li> 
                <li>Image2</li> 
                <li>Image3</li> 
                <li>Image4</li> 
                <li>Image5</li> 
                <li>Image6</li> 

            </ul> 
    </div>



    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The result nothing,a list of images!!(NB:i have changed the images src="" so that i can ask my question)
is there a problem?pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably got your answer by now after 3 years :)
Your problem is you should jcarousel the `div#slider`. According to jCarousel documentation:

> jCarousel expects a very basic HTML markup structure inside your HTML
>   document:

```
<div class="jcarousel"> <--------------------------------| Root element
    <ul> <-------------------------------| List element  |
        <li>...</li> <---| Item element  |               |
        <li>...</li> <---| Item element  |               |
    </ul> <------------------------------|               |
</div> <-------------------------------------------------|
```

> This structure is only an example and not required. You could also use
>   a structure like:

```
<div class="mycarousel"> <-------------------------------| Root element
    <div> <------------------------------| List element  |
        <p>...</p> <-----| Item element  |               |
        <p>...</p> <-----| Item element  |               |
    </div> <-----------------------------|               |
</div> <-------------------------------------------------|
```

> **The only requirement is, that it consists of a root element, list
>   element and item elements.**

So your script should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#slider').jcarousel({
             vertical: true,
             scroll: 2
         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the css like :

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
```

and referred the script files :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<!--
  jCarousel skin stylesheet
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skins/tango/skin.css" />
```

Comment: Yes,i have copied exactly the the files that are in http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

Dont you need to load JQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i Have added the jquery lib file,i'm  using it in other pages.

Comment: could u test the example in the link above.